# How to run hector_slam with bag file of laser scanner?

Tags: slam, navigation, laser, rosbag, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I record laser scanner data by "rosbag record" option. When I want to run hector_slam with the bag file I faced some errors.
I use these commands to run:

```
rosmake hector_slam
roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch
rosbag play test.bag --clock
```

and in the tab that tutorial.launch run, this error appear repeatedly:

Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: "map" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.

And also the output of "rosbag info filename.bag" was:

```
path:        2014-04-02-19-53-59.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    9:40s (580s)
start:       Apr 02 2014 19:54:00.22 (1396452240.22)
end:         Apr 02 2014 20:03:40.50 (1396452820.50)
size:        12.8 MB
messages:    6412
compression: none [17/17 chunks]
types:       diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray       [3cfbeff055e708a24c3d946a5c8139cd]
             dynamic_reconfigure/Config            [958f16a05573709014982821e6822580]
             dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription [757ce9d44ba8ddd801bb30bc456f946f]
             rosgraph_msgs/Log                     [acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb]
             sensor_msgs/LaserScan                 [90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]
topics:      /diagnostics                           579 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray 
             /hokuyo_node/parameter_descriptions      1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription
             /hokuyo_node/parameter_updates           1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/Config           
             /rosout                                  6 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log                     (2 connections)
             /scan                                 5825 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan
```

How can I solve this problem.?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147651/how-to-run-hector_slam-with-bag-file-of-laser-scanner?/) by [adroit89](https://answers.ros.org/users/14081/adroit89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
What does `rosbag info test.bag` output? (edit your question to include the output)

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
It seems that the trajectory server complains, because the transform is not published. I don't know how hector mapping works, but I would disable the trajectory server and first look into how to get he mapping part to work.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
I.e. make sure all the necessary topics and parameters are there. You can use rxgraph / rqt_graph to check that rosbag is connected to the mapping node on the laser topics.

**Comment by [adroit89](https://answers.ros.org/users/14081/adroit89/) on 2014-04-04**:
Actually I cant understand that which topics and parameter it exactly needs! I can run the bag file example that provided by hector darmstad. I am sure it is not my problem with laser device or hector slam package. It relates to parameters that bag file needs.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-06**:
Two immediate candidates you might need are the Odometry, the IMU info and the /tf topic, which are both included in the bag file. I think hector mapping can work without IMU, but maybe needs some form of odometry still?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-06**:
Moreover you might need to edit the launch files / parameters to account for your setup, i.e. topic and tf-frame names.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-06**:
Have you followed this tutorial closely? http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot
It discusses how to set up your parameters with and without odometry.

**Comment by [adroit89](https://answers.ros.org/users/14081/adroit89/) on 2014-04-07**:
Yes, I followed this tutorial before. I can solve that problem. It was related to tf setting. Now I face another problem! During process in hector_slam I visit this message a lot:  SearchDir angle change too
And it appears a lot and make problem for matching the data to map.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-08**:
If there is a different problem, you should open a seperate question about it and mark stefan's answer as accepted for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The trajectory server transform error seems to confuse a few people but is not fatal if it only happens once or twice on startup (see [here for explanation](http://answers.ros.org/question/115306/how-to-solve-tf-problem-for-hector-slam/)). We changed it so this doesn´t happen anymore recently, but .debs might not be updated yet.

Your bagfile does not contain tf information, which hector_mapping needs to transform scan data into the stabilized frame (see [setting up for your robot](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2